# Angular keep form field content in an component while routing to an other component

Tags: angular, forms, routes

First of all i have a few components where iam able to fill up form fields. During this process it should be possible, that you can route to another component. But when you do this and try to go back to the component with all form fields, they are not filled anymore. So what can i do to store all of those fields during the "workflow"?

Comment: can you show some code

Comment: As @SlawaEremin asked, some code would be good to review this. But at first, thought what I think you are trying to achieve is a way to store the form values while changing components. Check my answer if that is what you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You may save the data in the local storage, then get them back into the form if the app reloads or anything occurs.

```
// Set in local storage
localStorage.setItem(itemName, JSON.stringify(formValues)); 

// Retrieve data from localstorage 
retrievedForm = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(itemName));
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep data between different components, you can use a service